# copying instances to avoid changing java instance state

Tags: java, object

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Test{
    Point[] pq = null; 
    public Test(int Capacity) {
            Point[] pq = new Point[Capacity];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point point = new Point(); // suppose it has a given state `state` equal to 0
        Test test = new Test(1);
        test.pq[0] = point; // here test[0] has a `state` equal to 0
        point.state = 1 //Suppose now I change the `state` of the point instance variable to 1

    }
 ...}
public class Point{
    public Integer state = 0;
...
}
```

I changed the `state` of the point instance variable to 1
then `test.pq[0].state` is now equal to `1`. How can I prevent my code from this behavior ?

Edit 1, in the Point class, I added getter and setters and turned `public Integer state` into `private Integer state = 0`, I added this

```
public void copy(Point point){
    this.setState(point.getState())
}
```

when I call `Test test = new Test(1); test.pq[0].copy(point);`, I still get te same problem

Comment: Use a different `Point` object.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your code doesn't make any sense. test is not an array, pq is not defined, etc. So it's impossible to answer. Post compilable code.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry, it was indeed not clear, I have just edited my post

Comment: If you make state `private` or `protected` rather than `public`, main() will be unable to alter it directly. (If this is the answer you're looking for, you really need to work your way through a decent Java tutorial.)

Comment: Clone the object before putting it in the array? Though I don't think you're looking to do that huh

Comment: @keshlam I put my `state` variable private, added getters and setters and the result is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

The clean way to avoid this problem is to make the Point class immutable:

```
public final class Point
    private final int state;

    public Point(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }
    // no setter !
}
```

That way, nobody can modify the state of a point, and everything is safe.

If the point needs to be mutable, and you don't want to let callers modify the state of the points of your Test, then you'll have to make copies:

```
public class Test {

    private Point point; // it would be the same with an array or a list

    public class Test(Point p) {
        // defensive copy
        this.point = new Point(p.getState());
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        // defensive copy
        return new Point(p.getState());
    }
}
```

Or course, if your Test has a list or array of points, and if you make the array or list of points accessible from the outside, you can't guarantee anything. That's why every modification should go through a method of the test (that's what encapsulation is all about):

```
    public void addPoint(Point p) {
        pointList.add(new Point(p.getState());
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to do that without declaring the variable `state` final ?

Comment: You can make the state not final, but if the goal is for the object to be immutable, what would you gain by not making it final? final precisely makes sure that the field value can't change. If it can change, the object is not immutable anymore, and you need to make defensive copies to protect yourself. In addition, making the fields final brings more guarantees in terms of visibility in multi-threaded code.

Comment: sorry, I am very new to java. If I want to change the `state` value from the outside, can I do this when declaring the variable final ?

Comment: You precisely asked how to avoid being able to change the state value of a point of the test from the outside. My answer explains it: either you completely forbid changing the state, or you allow it, but then you make defensive copies to make sure the outside changes the state of copies of the points, and doesn't alter the points of the test.

Comment: sorry, I don't want to bother you, but I edited my post, I added some `copy` method but I don't understand why this time it is not working

Comment: Of course you have the same problem. Your copy method takes another point as argument, and modifies the current point. What defensive copies do is create another point, and copy the state of the current point to this new point. So that the current point stays unmodified. Why don't you use the code I provided in my answer?

Comment: ok sorry I have just understood what is going on ! thank you very much

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? You just have to apply the solution again. If you don't want the outside to modify the array, create a copy of the array. Or better, encapsulate the array inside an immutable class. It's quite simple: if something is immutable, you don't need to copy it. If something is mutable, you need to copy it, or return an immutable view of it (like `Collections.unmodifiableList()` does. Use collections instead of arrays).